# Change CSS class selector to id

Tags: css

Could someone please tell me how I would change my CSS from a class selectors (.nav) to id selectors (#nav). Help and a little explanation would be really helpful. Thanks!

CSS example:

```
ul.nav li ul ul
```

Comment: Given that you know how to select by id (`#nav`), what exactly is the question you're asking? Does this relate to specific HTML? If it does, can we see it? As this question is currently written, there's no way we can reasonably answer.

Comment: Seems like the answer is in the question itself. As you said, one is `.nav` and the other is `#nav`.

Comment: Ignore me, I read somewhere that I shouldn't use selectors on IDs and wondered if there was a better way or something I was missing. Mike below confirms what I actually had. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
ul#nav li ul ul { /* your styles */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav li ul ul
```

ID selector is independent of class or element. To find an element with id="nav" you select with #nav